# PROLOG predicate order

Tags: prolog, clpfd

I've got a very large number of equations which I am trying to use PROLOG to solve. However, I've come a minor cropper in that they are not specified in any sort of useful order- that is, some, if not many variables, are used before they are defined. These are all specified within the same predicate. Can PROLOG cope with the predicates being specified in a random order?

Comment: This could be slight useful  -

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425009/how-do-i-need-to-order-these-prolog-rules-so-i-can-run-my-program

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely... ni (in Italian, Yes *and* Not)

That is, ideally Prolog requires that you specify *what* must be computed, not *how*, writing down the *equations* controlling the solution in a fairly general logical form, [Horn clauses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horn_clause).

But this ideal is far from reach, and this is the point where we, as programmers, play a role. You should try to *topologically sort* formulae, if you want Prolog just apply arithmetic/algorithms.

But at this point, Prolog is not more useful than any other procedural language. It just make easier to do such topological sort, in sense that formulas can be [read](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=read/1) (this builtin it's a full Prolog parser!), variables identified and quantified easily, terms transformed, evaluated, and the like (metalanguages features, a strong point of Prolog).

Situation changes if you can use [CLP(FD)](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%27A.7%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/clpfd.html%27%29%29). Just an example, a bidirectional factorial (cool, isn't it?), from the documentation of the shining implementation that [Markus Triska](http://web.student.tuwien.ac.at/~e0225855/) developed for SWI-Prolog:

```
You can also use CLP(FD) constraints as a more declarative alternative for ordinary integer arithmetic with is/2, >/2 etc. For example:

:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

n_factorial(0, 1).
n_factorial(N, F) :- N #> 0, N1 #= N - 1, F #= N * F1, n_factorial(N1, F1).

This predicate can be used in all directions. For example:

?- n_factorial(47, F).
F = 258623241511168180642964355153611979969197632389120000000000 ;
false.

?- n_factorial(N, 1).
N = 0 ;
N = 1 ;
false.

?- n_factorial(N, 3).
false.

To make the predicate terminate if any argument is instantiated, add the (implied) constraint F #\= 0 before the recursive call. Otherwise, the query n_factorial(N, 0) is the only non-terminating case of this kind.
```

Thus if you write your equations in CLP(FD) you get much more chances to have your 'equation system' solved as is. SWI-Prolog has dedicated debugging for the low level details used to solve CLP(FD).

HTH

Comment: The library does not include some operators which I need- mostly binary operators.

Comment: I think that in SWI-Prolog the CLP(FD) library has most, if not all, arithmetic predicates. But if you miss one, then I can't see any other way than to reorder variables in your predicate.